# Laravel is using the default homestead user details to connect, even though these have been deleted

Tags: laravel-5, database-connection

I am using laravel 5.8.6 and can connect to my database using the artisan migration tool, and can read and write to the database using tinker with no issues.

When I launch the default scaffolding it fails to connect, complaining that the login failed for user homestead@localhost.

I have deleted the .env.example file and cleared the various cache files with no success.

A full search for homestead only reveals log entries:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (1045)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` =
```

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: I have the php development server running in a command window pretty much all the time - it could be this that's holding the original login / password combination. I will check and confirm if this solves the problem

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same problem, and it's really strange. In none of the files throughout the whole project (except the `.env.example`, `.gitignore` and error logs) does the string `homestead` even occur. Tinker works, migrations work... But accessing the app in the browser, there's this exact error message. I don't understand how that's even possible.

Comment: Ok, never mind, right after posting my comment I found a solution that I'm going to post as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I just couldn't wrap my mind around how that was even possible. Turns out I seem to have changed the `.env` file after having started the dev server via `php artisan serve`. It doesn't pick up changes in the `.env` config at runtime and it caches the configuration.

After running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

, shutting down the dev server and restarting it, the issue was resolved and the database connection successful with the correctly set database credentials.